# How do I retain url parameters the entire time a user browses my site?

Tags: url-rewriting, domain, site-url, parameter

We have customers that come from other sites and I would like to retain a url parameter [/?lead=openeye](http://openeye.net/?lead=openeye) throughout the time that they're browsing. That way when they fill out a form I can capture the lead for sales.

How do I retain url parameters the entire time they're browsing the site.

**Update..**

I've began using a combination of sessions and cookies to accomidate this. It sort of works but doesn't seem to stick for more than a few seconds between pages.

In the header

```
<?php 
    $lead = $_GET['lead']; $_SESSION['lead'] = $lead;
    $url = parse_url(get_bloginfo('url'));
    setcookie("lead", $lead, 0, $url['path'], $url['host']); (set) 
?>
```

To test

```
<?php 
    echo ($_COOKIE['lead']); // Lead Cookie
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better Answer:

`session_start(); $lead = $_GET['lead']; $_SESSION['lead'] = $lead;`

Then, create an additional field on the form, with the input hidden. For the value, I would echo out the $_SESSION, with a name that is easy to grab (lead works). then, wherever the form is processed, just add a line to grab the lead, and do with it what you want. –

Comment: It worked, but I'm finding that the session does not stick when moving between pages. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: Dont call session_start on each page - you are clearing out the session then. It should only be called once, and you might be able to avoid calling it altogether.

Comment: I updated the post with my current findings.

Comment: Any thoughts on this Mitchell?

Comment: Just figured it out - set the cookie to a longer expires. PHP.net says that lasts until the browser closes, but if you make it last longer, like 30 min (time()+60*30), you might have better luck.

Comment: Where should we put this code?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is to capture the query with a tool like Google Analytics, and set up your site to also track the form with it.

there really is not a good way to do it - meaning that I cannot think of any. It is best to use tools meant for the job.

Setup Google Analytics, and set your form up as a conversion goal.

Once people start to convert, you can see where they came from.

You could go a step further and log a custom variable in GA that will store the lead.

This method is much better, well supported, and removes any chance of tampering.

Comment: This is specifically for Sales, they need to see the information in the form that is submitted. Using Analytics will not cover it.

Comment: You could also store the value in a session variable as they come into the site, and add it to the form content when it is getting submitted in a hidden field.

Comment: that's a good point as well. Would you mind answering with specifics on how you would store and output the variable? I imagine it would be something like `session_start(); 
$lead = $_GET['lead'];
$_SESSION['lead'] = $lead;
$_POST[$lead];`

Comment: Up until the post, that is exactally right. However, I would create an additional field on the form, with the input hidden. For the value, I would echo out the $_SESSION, with a name that is easy to grab (lead works). then, wherever the form is processed, just add a line to grab the lead, and do with it what you want.

Comment: lol, if you put that in an answer I'll check it.